# Trying to learn JavaScript and use it to return only the address not the whole <a> tag

Tags: javascript

Hello and thank you in advance for any and all assistance.

I'm trying to teach myself the basics of JavaScript before I start a bootcamp. In the Prep course we are asked to return the header, first link text and first link href using document.querySelector(). The course showed us how to do the header and I was able to get the first link text. What I cannot seem to figure out is how to return JUST the address and NOT the whole  tag.

Some of the things I've tried:

```
document.querySelector('a href')
document.querySelector('a href=')
document.querySelector('a href=""')
document.querySelector('a').innerHTML
document.querySelector('a').innerText
document.querySelector('a href').innerHTML
document.querySelector('a href').innerText
```

Thanks again.

John

Comment: Please check this url https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_getattribute

Comment: Or try this ` var url = document.getElement("a").getAttribute("href");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href")
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to figure out. Thank you. P.S. Also thanks for the link recommendation - I've bookmarked it, great resource!

Answer (score 1):

First Understand that href is an attribute, not an element,  anchor is an element that accepts href as the attribute to get this attribute value you need to first get that anchor element then get its attribute value. For example:

`let anchor = document.querySelector("a");
let url = anchor.getAttribute("href");
console.log(url)`

`

```js
let anchor = document.querySelector("a");
let url = anchor.getAttribute("href");
console.log(url)
```

```html
<a href='https://stackoverflow.com/' tittle='stackOverflow'Stack Overflow></a>
```

`

Comment: Great info! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, to bring any attribute of the anchor tag

```
document.querySelector('a').attributes.href.value
```